# Haproxy Multiple Frontend and "NOT" Backend

Tags: haproxy

Did anyone tried to use Haproxy and bind a multiple port into Frontend block? I know Frontend is listening to port 80 and we have multiple Backend listening to different port. But is it possible to have Multiple Frontend instead of Multiple Backend?

Comment: Of course. You can bind as many as you like. :)

Comment: How am I going to do it? since I tried doing multiple Frontend configuration but it didnt work

Comment: Post your configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  bind *:443
  bind *:what
  bind *:ever
  bind *:you
  bind *:like
====followed by the rest of your config====
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks